# HTML contact form in PHP block

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts, contact-form

I'm relatively new to PHP so forgive me if this seems obvious. How would you integrate a block of HTML code like this:

```
 <form action="form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <label></label>
        <input name="name" required="required" placeholder="Your Name">


        <label></label>
        <input name="email" type="email" required="required" placeholder="Your Email">

            <label></label>
        <input name="address" type="name" required="required" placeholder="Your Address">


        <label></label>
        <textarea name="message" required > Dear Mr. X, Please support us...  </textarea>


        <input id="cancel" name="cancel" value="Cancel" />

        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>
```

into here:

```
if(empty($mpemail)){

echo "<h2>Send your MP our pre-written letter</h2>
<p>Unfortunately, your MP's email address is not listed in our database.</p>";
}

else {

echo "<h2>Send your MP our pre-written letter</h2>";
echo "<p>Please fill out the information required below:</p>";   
  **Insert Contact Form Here**
echo "<h2>Share this with your followers!</h2>";
echo '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button"          data-text="I just used EG4DEMUK\'s handy tool to write to my local MP about Egypt!" data-size="large" data-hashtags="writetoyourmp">Tweet </a>';
echo "<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>";
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Just end the php code using `?>` right after `echo "<p>Please fill out the information required below:</p>";` then insert your html code and finally switch over to php using `<?php` just before `echo "<h2>Share this with your followers!</h2>";`

Answer (score 1):

So, one option is to `echo` it out line by line, as your PHP code sample is doing, or in one big block. You can also combine PHP and HTML in the same file by starting and stopping the PHP interpreter. Here's an example of that:

```
if (empty($mpemail))
{
    echo "<h2>Send your MP our pre-written letter</h2>
    <p>Unfortunately, your MP's email address is not listed in our database.</p>";
}
else
{
?>

<h2>Send your MP our pre-written letter</h2>
<p>Please fill out the information required below:</p>

<form action="form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label></label>
    <input name="name" required="required" placeholder="Your Name">

    <label></label>
    <input name="email" type="email" required="required" placeholder="Your Email">

    <label></label>
    <input name="address" type="name" required="required" placeholder="Your Address">


    <label></label>
    <textarea name="message" required > Dear Mr. X, Please support us...  </textarea>

    <input id="cancel" name="cancel" value="Cancel" />
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


<h2>Share this with your followers!</h2>
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="I just used EG4DEMUK\'s handy tool to write to my local MP about Egypt!" data-size="large" data-hashtags="writetoyourmp">Tweet </a>

<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>

<?php
}
```

In a professional production application, the "right way" to do it is to separate your HTML from your PHP by putting the logic of your application in a separate PHP file, and then putting your HTML in a "template" which you load and display from PHP. [Here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/17/getting-started-with-php-templating/) is a bit of info about getting started with template engines and Model View Controller patterns in an application. But, for what you're trying to do, the example above of starting and stopping the interpreter should work for you.

Comment: I din't check the code, but the piece of advice right above me is very useful, and I know that by experience.

Comment: <textarea name="message" required="" placeholder="Your Message" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px; width: 395px;"> Dear <?php echo $mptitle $mpfirstname $mpsecondname ?> Please support us...  </textarea>" Works up till here and then it doesn't seem to work